# Filter wordpress users by metakey

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a duplicate of the all user dashboard in Wordpress - but to only show users who have both metakey 'shipping-address-verified' value equal to "1" and do not have a metakey called 'shipped'

I added the code below to functions.php

But the custom-users page created does not display any users.

Anyoe know why that might be?

'shipping-address-verified' value is stored as an array :
array (
0 => '1',
)

```
// Add custom page to the WordPress admin menu
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_users_menu_page' );

function custom_users_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Custom Users', // Page title
        'Custom Users', // Menu title
        'manage_options', // Capability required to access the page
        'custom-users', // Menu slug
        'custom_users_callback' // Callback function to render the page
    );
}

// Render the custom users page
function custom_users_callback() {
    // Define the meta query to filter users
    $meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'shipping-address-verified',
        'value'   => array( '1' ),
        'compare' => 'IN',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'shipped',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    )
    );

    // Query users that match the meta query
    $args = array(
        'meta_query' => $meta_query,
        'fields'     => 'all_with_meta',
        'orderby'    => 'user_registered',
        'order'      => 'DESC'
    );
    $users_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
    $users = $users_query->get_results();

    // Render the users table
    $users_table = _get_list_table( 'WP_Users_List_Table' );
    $users_table->items = $users;
    $users_table->prepare_items();

    // Output the users table
    echo '<div class="wrap"><h1>Custom Users</h1>';
    $users_table->display();
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I doubt that `'value'   => array( '1' ),` does anything meaningful. Can you please explain, what _exactly_ _"value is stored as an array : array ( 0 => '1', )"_ is supposed to mean? What does the actual database column contain?

Comment: Hi @CBroe, the datbase value is "1" - I think it is stored as an array

Comment: Just a `1` is likely not meant to be an array, but if you are using the IN comparison operator with an array, that should still work. What happens when you try both conditions separately, on their own - do these queries each return users then?

Comment: @aid54 did you manage to find a solution? I've tried your code by changing the $meta_query and it does not display any users. I think that the problem is not on your query but in the output